# gdbserver on arm7hf gdb-multiarch on ubuntu with stripped symbol file

Tags: c++, debugging, gdbserver

I have a C++ application running on an embedded platform arm7hf arch. The binary has its symbols stripped by using objcopy (man page steps for objcopy flag --only-keep-debug 3 steps). The stripped symbols are saved in a x.debug file.

I have the cross compiled application running on my embedded system. While logged into the embedded system, I can run gdb and load the stripped symbols with the `gdb> symbol-file ./path/to/x.debug` then when I break everything looks great! So I conformed that the symbols are correct and can be used by gdb to debug.

What I really want to do is remotely debug using gdbserver and gdb-multiarch. I run `gdbserver --attach $(pidof ProcName)` on the embedded system and on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I run `gdb-multiarch ./path/to/arm7hf/ProcName`.

I've tried using the flag to gdb-multiarch `-symbols=./path/to/x.debug` and I've tried doing the gdb command `gdb> symbol-file ./path/to/x.debug` to no vail. When I try to break or bt I get error `Cannot access memory at address 0x1`. After some research that error seems to mean gdb has no symbol information.

Can someone give guidance to what I am doing wrong on the client-side (ubuntu gdb-multiarch)

Comment: `gdbserver --attach PID` is not a complete command. Please show how you *actually* run `gdbserver`, and how you connect `gdb` to it.

Comment: gdbserver --attach 0.0.0.0:6806 <PID>

I got assistance. Required doing:
`set sysroot /path/to/toolchain/so/libs`